# Conditional sentences in the past

Tags: conditionals

In conditional sentences to denote a condition in the present if+past tense and a modal(in the past form)+ the first form of verb is used.As - If I had money I would open a library. To denote a situation in the past if + past perfect tense and a modal(in the past form)+ have+ the third form of verb is used. As If he had gone there he would have met him.But what will be the sentence if the if clause is in the past and the modal clause is in the present. As here is a situation - in a cricket match the toss has happened and it is in the past and the batting is yet to start, that is in the present. What will in the meantime the captain say - If we had won the toss ,we would have also batted first. Or If we had won the toss we would also bat first. As batting has not happened yet. Which of these sentences is right here or are both the sentences right in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case of a conditional involving a past event and future situation:

> If **we had** won the toss, **we would be** batting first.